# Is it possible to use nested linked libraries in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to set up a quite generic set of libraries to enhance my workspace and want to set up a nested set of library components. Each component lives in its own library file and collections of related components are collected into library files with each component a linked reference to the individual file. What I am trying to do is set up a root library file that recursively includes linked sub-libraries down to the individual components. The problem is if a library contains a linked subsystem that is itself a library, the Library Browser does not allow expanding the library into its sub-blocks  with the '+' symbol.

Is it possible to create a library in this way and have Library Browser expand the linked sublibraries?

Comment: I am not sure on the top of my head, but I had similar problems. It doesn't let you do that. However, in your `slblocks` file there must be some scripting you can do that can dictate how nested your libraries should be. This problem could also be down to the fact that the visibility of nested non-atomic/atomic subsystem blocks.

Comment: I'm not sure the purpose of going down to the individual block level, rather than functional groups of blocks. I guess on a git diff it would be nice to directly see which blocks have changed. But even if you split every block out, you will still have a subsystem with a name respresenting it in your sub-library - the only missing piece will be the actual nesting of that on the left. Why is that feature important? Or is the intent to go multiple levels down?

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem you can use multiple levels of nesting in the way you describe, you may not actually need the intermediate libraries.

If you are only creating intermediate libraries to link the next level down, then they can just be replaced with a subsystem, keep nesting subsystems as needed until you get down to the lowest library level (in your case the library files with just single blocks in them), then reference those final library block files with a reference subsystem (i.e. linking them in the Open callback).

Simulink will nest the subsystems in the browser as many levels as you want to put, and then at the lowest level if you use the referenced subsystems to refer to the single block libraries, those will unnest and show the actual blocks at the lowest level.

So, you end up with just the top level libraries that have a bunch of nested subsystems, that create the hierarchy you want, with references to the individual block libraries at the bottom of the hierarchy.